# Selecting Transforms with sklearn pipelines

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, normalization, model-selection, pipelines

So I am currently working on a Data set, and I want to use Pipelines to select the transforms. Here is an example of what I want to do :

```py
# I missed the imports just for brevity
pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), PolynomialFeatures(), PCA(), LogisticRegression())
```

So what I want to do, I want to try both StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler and no scaler when I am using other methods such as XGBOOST. Then I want to try to use polynomial features and then use a PCA, only if I used polynomial features. And finally, I want to try Logistic Regression and XGBOOST with GridSearch (This last part I know how to do).

Anybody did something similar?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of this here:

https://iaml.it/blog/optimizing-sklearn-pipelines

Comment: How do you make it to accept your own answers as the accepted one?

Comment: I just clicked on the tick on the left why?

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of the pipeline is to assemble several steps that can be
> cross-validated together while setting different parameters. For this,
> it enables setting parameters of the various steps using their names

Check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)

For your requirement, you will have to create multiple pipelines, you cannot do it via single pipeline.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of what the documentation says. I was wondering if someone had an elegant solution for this anyway.